# How to inject Sqlite into Bottle application for Webtest?

Tags: python, sqlite, unit-testing, bottle, webtest

This is my application (using [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html)):

```
import bottle
app = bottle.Bottle()
@app.get('/')
def home(db):
  return bottle.template('Hi!')
if __name__ == '__main__':
  bottle.install(bottle_sqlite.SQLitePlugin(dbfile='data.db'))
  bottle.run()
```

This is a unit test (with [webtest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WebTest) and [unittest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html)):

```
import webtest
def test_home():
  app = webtest.TestApp(example.app)
  assert app.get('/').status == '200 OK'
```

It doesn't work, because `data.db` is not available during testing. The goal is to somehow inject that `db` into the application before running the tests. How should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should either create a mockup of the SQLitePlugin that fakes a database (by using a python dictionary), or create and destroy a SQLite database (with a dataset matching your tests) before and after each set of tests.

basically, you could do something like:

```
import webtest
def test_home():
  plugin = bottle_sqlite.SQLitePlugin(dbfile='my_test_data_set.db')
  example.app.install(plugin)
  app = webtest.TestApp(example.app)
  assert app.get('/').status == '200 OK'
  example.app.uninstall(plugin)
```

or

```
import webtest
def test_home():
  plugin = bottle_sqlite.SQLitePluginMockup(dataset)
  example.app.install(plugin)
  app = webtest.TestApp(example.app)
  assert app.get('/').status == '200 OK'
  example.app.uninstall(plugin)
```

where dataset would be a "hand made" dictionary faking the dataset for your application.

Or you may be able to do it once and for all in global context of your test script.

HTH